# Import Objective-C class in Swift file in Objective-C Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I'm currently working with Objective-C project, and i'm using some swift files in that so created bridge header like APPNAME-Swift.h. and i'm able to import in objective-C classes. But here my problem is i need to import objective-c class in swift file.

here is example:

> Objective-C project>drag and drop swift files ClassA.swift,
> ClassB.swift into project and created bridge. Now in objective-C class
> i'm able to use swift classes in objective-c classes like below
> Appdelegate.h i imported #import "<#YourProjectName#>-Swift.h"
>
> now i need to import Appdelegate.h in ClassB.swift.

Please Help me on it

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create the file "APPNAME-Swift.h" in your project, it will be generated automatically during build and you should not try to modify this file. You can create bridging header for your project but I guess You don't have a problem with it. I just recommend you to rename your bridging header, because I guess that the generated file "APPNAME-Swift.h" has the same name as your bridging header, that's why you have a problem.

After you will rename your bridging header change your build settings. You will need to change a string at Build Settings -> Objective-C Bridging Header (see attached image for more information):

[image: Setup of bridging headers]

If you want to change name of the file "APPNAME-Swift.h" you need also modify your build settings. You can do it at Build Settings -> Objective C Generated Interface Header Name (see attached image for more information):

[image: Setup of the Objective C interface file]

In your bridging header add the following line:

```
#import "MyObjectiveCClass.h"
```

And after that you will be able to use class `MyObjectiveCClass` (Objective-C) in your Swift code (if file "MyObjectiveCClass.h" contains a class called "MyObjectiveCClass").

All settings provided for Xcode 9.2.

Comment: Thanks for response i agree with you. its generated bridge header and i am able to use swift classes in objective-C, but i need to use objetive-c class in swift file as well

Comment: @BoosaRamesh What is name of your bridging header? Or maybe you use different headers for each target?

Comment: ProjectName/ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h, its generated automatically after drag and drop swift classes in objective-C project. i am able to use all swift classes in my project. but here the problem is i need import on of objective class like app delegate in swift class. i couldnt import

Comment: @BoosaRamesh Could you please add code from your bridging header to this question?